# I cannot send data from my form to typescript angular

Tags: angular, database, typescript, forms, express

I try to develop a fullstack application with node js and angular (material ui).
I block on problem on the following problem.

how to recover data from the form angular  ?
I am making a small web resource management application. I am currently in the registration and sending phase of data in a Mysql database.

[image: this.siguoForm.value]

server, he send the request  :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var mysql = require('mariadb');
const body = require("body-parser");
app.use(body.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(body.json());
app.use(cors());

var connection = mysql.createPool({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '',
  database : 'totale',
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
  console.log(req);
});

app.post("/inscription",(req,res)=>{
  var nom = req.body.name;
  var prenom = req.body.lastname;
  var mail = req.body.email;
  var password = req.body.password;
  connection.getConnection().then(conn => {
    conn.query("INSERT INTO `inscription` (nom,prenom,mail,password) values (?,?,?,?);",[nom,prenom,mail,password],function(err, rows) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
      });
  });
  //connection.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

HTML form:

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(signupForm)" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" id='email' name='email' matInput placeholder="Enter your email"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input type="text"  id='name' name='name' matInput placeholder="Nom">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
           <input  type="text"  id='lastname' name='lastname' matInput placeholder="Prenom" >
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input type="password" id='password' name='password' type="password" matInput placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
              <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
          </button>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button>Inscription</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

TYPESCRIPT, take data:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { User } from './../User';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-inscription',
  templateUrl: './inscription.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inscription.component.css']
})

export class InscriptionComponent implements OnInit {
  signupForm;
  results;


  constructor (private http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder)
  {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.signupForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email :"",
      name :"",
      lastname :"",
      password :"",
    });
  }
  public onFormSubmit() {
    const configUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/inscription';
    this.http.post(configUrl,this.signupForm.value)
    .pipe(
      tap(
        data => console.log(configUrl, data),
        error => console.log(configUrl, error)
      )
    )
    .subscribe(results => this.results = results);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the formControlName attribute to all of your form fields.

change your form like below, then your form data will be available in your ts file.

```
<form [formGroup]="signupForm" class="example-form" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(signupForm)" novalidate>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" id='email' name='email' formControlName="email" matInput placeholder="Enter your email"/>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input type="text"  id='name' name='name' formControlName="name" matInput placeholder="Nom">
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
           <input  type="text"  id='lastname' name='lastname' formControlName="lastname" matInput placeholder="Prenom" >
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <input type="password" id='password' name='password' formControlName="password" type="password" matInput placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
              <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'" [attr.aria-pressed]="hide">
          </button>
  </mat-form-field>
  <div class="example-button-row">
    <button type="submit" mat-raised-button>Inscription</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

make this little change to onFormSubmit function.

```
public onFormSubmit() {
    const configUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/inscription';
    this.http.post(configUrl,this.signupForm.value)
    .subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results;
    });
 }
```

and just log the `console.log(req.body)` on API side. if still data is not coming check the configuration and if there is error please describe.